# Does my game keep running if I physically turn off the monitor? How about Digitally?

Tags: windows, display, graphics-card, gpu, external-display

I am playing a game on Windows 10 21h2. I have some bots working in the background using image detection of the game.

Furthermore, I was wondering does the game and the bot keep running if I turn off the monitor physically (by using the switch on it)?

Does the game/bot keep doing its job?

How about turning it off digitally? Through software like this: https://github.com/arjun024/turn-off-screen

FWIW, I set up my PC to never sleep.
Also, I am not using a laptop I am using regular PC.

Comment: In all likelihood, yes it continues to run.  Software can be programmed to detect display status but I seriously doubt your game does.  Have you tried it?  Did your bot show progress withe the display off?

Comment: Lots of systems run headless just fine. I have done that myself when travelling away from home.

Comment: Turning off your monitor unless it's a laptop and you are closing the lid will allow any and all applications to continue running.   However, software might have bot detection, so the software might not work if you turn your screen off.

Comment: On laptops one can disable the screen by just leaving the PC alone for a while. For example, in macOS the display will turn off after a specific period of inactivity. But programs might stop running as well; thus using “caffeinate” for some cases and such. So basically if the display is physically turned off, the PC will run fine. If the PC is set to never go to sleep that is fine but you might consider setting it up so the display goes to sleep.

Comment: I am not using a laptop I am using regular PC.